# make select option selected by index with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to make selected select option by index. I do something like that but no luck

```
$('select.caratA options:eq(10)').attr('selected', 'selected') 
// or
$('select.caratA option:eq(10)').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('select.caratAoption').eq(10).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.val()` just returns the value and doesn't set anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('select.caratA').prop('selectedIndex', '9');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4LV4S/)

Comment: Clearly the most concise and best solution.

Comment: Thanks, don't really use `selectedIndex` very often, but for setting the selects value based on index it seemed appropriate, as that is exactly what `selectedIndex` is for.

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $('select.caratA option').eq(10).val();
$('select.caratA').val(val);
```

This will get you the value of the option with the specified index, then set that option as selected.

Answer (score 1):

use `.prop()`

```
$('select.caratA option:eq(10)').prop('selected',true);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/E3kZy/3/

Comment: doesn't work by some reason. I do  $('select.caratA option:eq(10)').prop('selected', true); console.log($('select.caratA').val()); Result 0.32 but option still not selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('select :nth-child(5)').prop('selected',true)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E3kZy/4/